# Nontrivial extension of cyclic group by simple group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group, simple-groups, group-extensions

Let $ G $ be a (non-abelian) finite simple group. An extension $ G\cdot m $ is nontrivial if it is not isomorphic to the direct product $ G \times m $. Suppose that there exists a nontrivial extension $ G\cdot m $ where $ m $ is a cyclic group of order $ m $. Prove that for every $ n $ divisible by $ m $ there exists a nontrivial extension $ G.n $.

Are the assumptions on $ G $ necessary? Or is it even true more generally that if there exists a nontrivial extension $ G\cdot m $ where $ m $ is a cyclic group of order $ m $ then for every $ n $ divisible by $ m $ there exists a nontrivial extension $ G.n $.

Comment: This question is much too broad, and I am not sure what sort of answer you are expecting. The outer automorphism groups of all finite simple groups are known, so I guess the answer to your question is also known: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups). Not also that is a non-trivial extension exists for some $m$ then it exists for all multiples of $m$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah ok so is the answer that all extensions $ G.m $ are trivial if and only if $ m $ is relatively prime to the order of $ Out(G) $? I guess what I'm most interested in is the last fact you mentioned "if a non-trivial extension exists for some 
 then it exists for all multiples of " If I changed my question to be "How do you show that if there exists a nontrivial extension $ G.m $ then there exists a nontrivial extension for all multiples of $ m $?" would the question no longer be too broad?

Comment: If  you have a nontrivial extension $G.m$, then, for any $k>1$, you get  nontrivial extension $G.(km)$ by taking a subdirect product with a cyclic group of order $mk$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh interesting I'm not familiar with subdirect products. What does that mean? For example what would this look like in the case $ G=A_5 $, $ m=2 $, $ G.m=S_5 $ and $ k=2 $ to get a $ A_5.4 $ group?

Comment: It's a subgroup of index $2$ in $S_5 \times C_4$.